# Mean and standard deviation of lognormal distribution do not match analytic values

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, mean, standard-deviation

As part of my research, I measure the mean and standard deviation of draws from a lognormal distribution. Given a value of the underlying **normal** distribution, it should be possible to analytically predict these quantities (as given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

However, as can be seen in the plots below, this does not seem to be the case. The first plot shows the mean of the lognormal data against the sigma of the gaussian, while the second plot shows the sigma of the lognormal data against that of the gaussian. Clearly, the "calculated" lines deviate from the "analytic" ones very significantly.

I take the mean of the gaussian distribution to be related to the sigma by `mu = -0.5*sigma**2` as this ensures that the lognormal field ought to have mean of 1. Note, this is motivated by the area of physics that I work in: the deviation from analytic values still occurs if you set `mu=0.0` for example.

By copying and pasting the code at the bottom of the question, it should be possible to reproduce the plots below. Any advice as to what might be causing this would be much appreciated!

Mean of lognormal vs sigma of gaussian:
[image: Mean of lognormal vs sigma of gaussian]

Sigma of lognormal vs sigma of gaussian:
[image: Sigma of lognormal vs sigma of gaussian]

Note, to produce the plots above, I used `N=10000`, but have put `N=1000` in the code below for speed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean_calc = []
sigma_calc = []
mean_analytic = []
sigma_analytic = []
ss = np.linspace(1.0,10.0,46)
N = 1000

for s in ss:
  mu = -0.5*s*s
  ln = np.random.lognormal(mean=mu, sigma=s, size=(N,N))
  mean_calc += [np.average(ln)]
  sigma_calc += [np.std(ln)]
  mean_analytic += [np.exp(mu+0.5*s*s)]
  sigma_analytic += [np.sqrt((np.exp(s**2)-1)*(np.exp(2*mu + s*s)))]

plt.loglog(ss,mean_calc,label='calculated')
plt.loglog(ss,mean_analytic,label='analytic')
plt.legend();plt.grid()
plt.xlabel(r'$\sigma_G$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\mu_{LN}$')
plt.show()

plt.loglog(ss,sigma_calc,label='calculated')
plt.loglog(ss,sigma_analytic,label='analytic')
plt.legend();plt.grid()
plt.xlabel(r'$\sigma_G$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\sigma_{LN}$')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think it is wrong - the formula you use there is equivalent to the one I have, as shown in the "Definition" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance. I could use np.std, you're right, but that gives exactly the same results. I will update the question to use np.std as it is cleaner.

Comment: Note: the above comment was added after a user commented suggesting that my formula for "sigma_calc" was wrong. They have since deleted their comment, and hopefully the new formula - using np.std - is more clear.

Comment: Some of your formulas do seem wrong. For example, `mu = -0.5*s*s` try this with a few numbers. I tried it with s=5 and my result was -12.5, not 5.

similarly, tour mean_analytic calculation seems confusing. Once the mean calculations are fixed, then it makes sense to evaluate whether the SD calculations are correct.

However, I don't think it makes sense to delete someone's comment. The users are trying to help you, and their comments help other users understand the situation

Comment: Surely with `s=5`, `mu=-12.5` is exactly what you would expect? `-0.5*5*5 = -0.5*25 = -12.5`? The "analytic" formulae are taken from the wikipedia page linked, and I believe they are right - is there a reason you think they're not?  Just to be clear, **I did not delete the comment, the user themselves deleted it**. I appreciate they were trying to help, but it is not helpful for them to have since deleted their comment!

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding the goal here, but maybe a little better. so ss is a vector of SD values for distributions you are creating? and you are setting the mean of each created distribution to half of the square of the SD? Why are you taking the mean of your created distributions, since you explicitly set the mean for each of them?

Comment: Sorry it isn't clear. Basically, in my research I want to choose the value of the gaussian sigma so that I get a particular value of the lognormal sigma (there are more complications, but I don't think they're helpful here). Things weren't working as I expected, so I decided to make a plot of my "input" gaussian sigma vs my "output" lognormal sigma.

Comment: I set the gaussian mean to minus half of the variance as this ought to produce a lognormal field with mean 1 for any value of the gaussian sigma (the formulae on the wikipedia page show this). The motivation for this is from the area of physics I work in. I measure the mean of the **lognormal** field, whereas I set the mean of the **gaussian** field - in theory, specifying the latter (along with the gaussian sigma) should analytically determine the former, but my plots seem to show that this isn't the case.

Comment: I suspect that I'm just implementing something incorrectly, but I've not been able to find an error yet!

Comment: I have now edited the question to remove unnecessary information, hopefully it is more clear now!

Comment: ok. I typically work w gaussian but not lognormal. However, I discovered last year that np.std defaults to df= N, whereas in my field we typically use df= N-1. so maybe something similar is going on here.

Comment: It might be an issue with outliers and pseudo-random generator. As sigma grows, outliers become stronger, if the pseudo random generator lack intensity in outliers your calculated mean and standard deviation will be smaller than expected

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not sure that could cause a deviation this large? And certainly it shouldn't cause any problems with the mean, which doesn't use np.std.

Comment: @jlandercy, this was along the lines of what I thought might be the problem. Can you explain any further? Would first generating a "standard" gaussian (mean=0, variance=1), then scaling using the sigma and mu I want, and then taking the exponential fix this?

Comment: Using `scipy.stats` I have the same phenomenon for large sigma, but it is smooth, I replaced your sampling by: `ln = scipy.stats.lognorm(s, scale=np.exp(mu)).rvs(N*N, random_state=1)`. I have no time for the moment but I will investigate this later.

Comment: I think the reason it is smooth is because you fix the random state? Either way, interesting that the same problem occurs with scipy.stats. Please let me know if you find anything interesting - I will continue to investigate in the mean time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how scipy.stats works, but when I call `scipy.stats.lognorm(s, scale=np.exp(mu)).rvs(N*N, random_state=1)` consecutively, I am returned exactly the same random numbers. If I use your formula for `ln` then I get a smooth curve, whereas removing the `random_state=1` returns the same jagged line as before.

Comment: Let me know if the answer helped you. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer - I'm just thinking about it now and trying to reproduce your plots. I'll get back to you once I've had a think, but it certainly looks promising!

Comment: I am glad to help, if you find out the answer suits you, please mark it.

Comment: You are right, it is smooth because of `random_state`, removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Lognormal are positively skewed and heavy tailed distribution. When performing float arithmetic operations (such as sum, mean or std) on sample drawn from a highly skewed distribution, the sampling vector contains values with discrepancy over several order of magnitude (many decades). This makes the computation inaccurate.

The problem comes from those two lines:

```
mean_calc += [np.average(ln)]
sigma_calc += [np.std(ln)]
```

Because `ln` contains both very low and very high values with order of magnitude much higher than float precision.

The problem can be easily detected to warn user that its computation are wrong using the following predicate:

```
 (max(ln) + min(ln)) <= max(ln)
```

Which is obviously false in Strictly Positive Real but must be considered when using Finite Precision Arithmetic.

#### Modifying your MCVE

If we slightly modify your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to:

```
from scipy import stats

for s in ss:
    mu = -0.5*s*s
    ln = stats.lognorm(s, scale=np.exp(mu)).rvs(N*N)
    f = stats.lognorm.fit(ln, floc=0)
    mean_calc += [f[2]*np.exp(0.5*s*s)]
    sigma_calc += [np.sqrt((np.exp(f[0]**2)-1)*(np.exp(2*mu + s*s)))]
    mean_analytic += [np.exp(mu+0.5*s*s)]
    sigma_analytic += [np.sqrt((np.exp(s**2)-1)*(np.exp(2*mu + s*s)))]
```

It gives the reasonably correct mean and standard deviation estimation even for high value of sigma.

[image]
[image]

The key is that [`fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) uses MLE algorithm to estimates parameters. This totally differs from your original approach which directly performs the mean of the sample.

The `fit` method returns a tuple with `(sigma, loc=0, scale=exp(mu))` which are parameters of the [`scipy.stats.lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) object as specified in documentation.

I think you should investigate how you are estimating mean and standard deviation. The divergence probably comes from this part of your algorithm.

There might be several reasons why it diverges, at least consider:

- <strike>Biased estimator: Are your estimator correct and unbiased?</strike> Mean is unbiased estimator (see next section) but maybe not efficient;
- <strike>Sampled outliers from Pseudo Random Generator may not be as intense as they should be compared to the theoretical distribution: maybe MLE is less sensitive than your estimator</strike> New MCVE bellow does not support this hypothesis, but Float Arithmetic Error can explain why your estimators are underestimated;
- **Float Arithmetic Error** New MCVE bellow highlights that it is part of your problem.

#### A scientific quote

It seems naive mean estimator (simply taking mean), even if unbiased, is inefficient to properly estimate mean for large sigma (see **Qi Tang**, [Comparison of Different Methods for Estimating Log-normal Means](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.854.6476&rep=rep1&type=pdf), p. 11):

> The naive estimator is easy to calculate and it is unbiased. However,
>   this estimator can be inefficient when variance is large and sample
>   size is small.

The thesis reviews several methods to estimate mean of a lognormal distribution and uses MLE as reference for comparison. This explains why your method has a drift as sigma increases and MLE stick better alas it is not time efficient for large N. Very interesting paper.

#### Statistical considerations

Recalling than:

- [Lognormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) is a [heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) and long tailed distribution positively skewed. One consequence is: as the shape parameter sigma grows, the asymmetry and skweness grows, so does the strength of outliers.
- Effect of Sample Size: as the number of samples drawn from a distribution grows, the expectation of having an outlier increases (so does the extent).

[image]
[image]

#### Building a new MCVE

Lets build a new MCVE to make it clearer. The code bellow draws samples of different sizes (`N` ranges between `100` and `10000`) from lognormal distribution where shape parameter varies (`sigma` ranges between `0.1` and `10`) and scale parameter is set to be unitary.

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Make computation reproducible among batches:
np.random.seed(123456789)

# Parameters ranges:
sigmas = np.arange(0.1, 10.1, 0.1)
sizes = np.logspace(2, 5, 21, base=10).astype(int)

# Placeholders:
rv = np.empty((sigmas.size,), dtype=object)
xmean = np.full((3, sigmas.size, sizes.size), np.nan)
xstd = np.full((3, sigmas.size, sizes.size), np.nan)
xextent = np.full((2, sigmas.size, sizes.size), np.nan)
eps = np.finfo(np.float64).eps

# Iterate Shape Parameter:
for (i, s) in enumerate(sigmas):
    # Create Random Variable:
    rv[i] = stats.lognorm(s, loc=0, scale=1)
    # Iterate Sample Size:
    for (j, N) in enumerate(sizes):
        # Draw Samples:
        xs = rv[i].rvs(N)
        # Sample Extent:
        xextent[:,i,j] = [np.min(xs), np.max(xs)]
        # Check (max(x) + min(x)) <= max(x)
        if (xextent[0,i,j] + xextent[1,i,j]) - xextent[1,i,j] < eps:
            warnings.warn("Potential Float Arithmetic Errors: logN(mu=%.2f, sigma=%2f).sample(%d)" % (0, s, N))
        # Generate different Estimators:
        # Fit Parameters using MLE:
        fit = stats.lognorm.fit(xs, floc=0)
        xmean[0,i,j] = fit[2]
        xstd[0,i,j] = fit[0]
        # Naive (Bad Estimators because of Float Arithmetic Error):
        xmean[1,i,j] = np.mean(xs)*np.exp(-0.5*s**2)
        xstd[1,i,j] = np.sqrt(np.log(np.std(xs)**2*np.exp(-s**2)+1))
        # Log-transform:
        xmean[2,i,j] = np.exp(np.mean(np.log(xs)))
        xstd[2,i,j] = np.std(np.log(xs))
```

Observation: The new MCVE starts to raise warnings when `sigma > 4`.

#### MLE as Reference

Estimating shape and scale parameters using MLE performs well:

[image]
[image]

The two figures above show than:

- Error on estimation grows alongside with shape parameter;
- Error on estimation reduces as sample size increases ([CTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem));

Note than MLE also fits well the shape parameter:

[image]

#### Float Arithmetic

It is worthy to plot the extent of drawn samples versus shape parameter and sample size:

[image]

Or the decimal magnitude between smallest and largest number form the sample:

[image]

On my setup:

```
np.finfo(np.float64).precision  # 15
np.finfo(np.float64).eps        # 2.220446049250313e-16
```

It means we have at maximum 15 significant figures to work with, if the magnitude between two numbers exceed then the largest number absorb the smaller ones.

**A basic example:** What is the result of `1 + 1e6` if we can only keep four significant figures?
The exact result is `1,000,001.0` but it must be rounded off to `1.000e6`. This implies: the result of the operation equals to the highest number because of the rounding precision. It is inherent of *Finite Precision Arithmetic*.

The two previous figures above in conjunction with statistical consideration supports your observation that increasing `N` does not improve estimation for large value of `sigma` in your MCVE.

Figures above and below show than when `sigma > 3` we haven't enough significant figures (less than 5) to performs valid computations.

Further more we can say that **estimator will be underestimated** because largest numbers will absorb smallest and the underestimated sum will then be divided by `N` making the estimator biased by default.

**When shape parameter becomes sufficiently large, computations are strongly biased because of [Arithmetic Float Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).**

It means using quantities such as:

```
np.mean(xs)
np.std(xs)
```

When computing estimate will have huge Arithmetic Float Error because of the important discrepancy among values stored in `xs`. Figures below reproduce your issue:

[image]
[image]

As stated, estimations are in default (not in excess) because high values (few outliers) in sampled vector absorb small values (most of the sampled values).

#### Logarithmic Transformation

If we apply a [logarithmic transformation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4120293/), we can drastically reduces this phenomenon:

```
xmean[2,i,j] = np.exp(np.mean(np.log(xs)))
xstd[2,i,j] = np.std(np.log(xs))
```

And then the naive estimation of the mean [is correct](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10842/expected-value-of-a-transformation) and will be far less affected by Arithmetic Float Error *because all sample values will lie within few decades instead of having relative magnitude higher than the float arithmetic precision*.

Actually, taking the log-transform returns the same result for mean and std estimation than MLE for each `N` and `sigma`:

```
np.allclose(xmean[0,:,:], xmean[2,:,:])  # True
np.allclose(xstd[0,:,:], xstd[2,:,:])    # True
```

#### Reference

If you are looking for complete and detailed explanations of this kind of issues when performing scientific computing, I recommend you to [read the excellent book](https://books.google.be/books?hl=en&lr=&id=7J52J4GrsJkC&oi=fnd&pg=PR3&dq=higham%20accuracy&ots=B5j1tkttZ2&sig=jmSAk3_InztrCJVc1yfRjZh1QGM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=higham%20accuracy&f=false): ***N. J. Higham***, Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Siam, Second Edition, 2002.

#### Bonus

Here an example of figure generation code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
idx = slice(None, None, 5)
axe.loglog(sigmas, xmean[0,:,idx])
axe.axhline(1, linestyle=':', color='k')
axe.set_title(r"MLE: $x \sim \log\mathcal{N}(\mu=0,\sigma)$")
axe.set_xlabel(r"Standard Deviation, $\sigma$")
axe.set_ylabel(r"Mean Estimation, $\hat{\mu}$")
axe.set_ylim([0.1,10])
lgd = axe.legend([r"$N = %d$" % s for s in sizes[idx]] + ['Exact'], bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper left')
axe.grid(which='both')
fig.savefig('Lognorm_MLE_Emean_Sigma.png', dpi=120, bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: could you post the exact code used to produce the plots you made? I am running the code as I understand it now but do not achieve the same plots using N=1000. Using N=10000 might work but seems to take a very long time to run (tens of hours) - is this what you did?

Comment: Update: using N=10000 doesn't seem to help unfortunately, so any clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's very helpful thanks! Would you be able to post the _exact_ code you used to generate your plots? As I mentioned, I'm having difficulty reproducing them at the moment